# Change the color of bullets in a frame using pause

Tags: beamer, color, itemize, pause

I want to change the color of a bulletted list in a frame using `\pause` command (or equivalent like `\onslide`), i.e. my list is first displayed in black and I want it gray on the next step.

What I am doing :

```
\begin{center}
    \color<2->{light-gray} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Bruit
        \item Fragilité mécanique
        \item Entretient
        \item Jeu dans les engrenages
    \end{itemize}
\end{center}
```

The results is ok (the text changes color at the second step) but not for the bullets that do not change color. So I try to solve this problem by adding the following line :

```
\onslide<2-> \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=light-gray} \onslide<1->
```

But the change on colors for the bullet appears at both steps and not only on step 2. I suppose that such command don't work with `\onslide`, so I search an idea to change my bullet colors only on the second step.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress, aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcommand{\itemcolor}[1]{% Update list item colour
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\color{#1}\hfil ##1}}

\begin{document}
     \begin{frame}
         \begin{center}
             %\onslide<2-> \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=light-gray}
             %\onslide<1->
             \begin{itemize}
                 \color<2->{light-gray} 
                 \item Item1
                 \item Item2
                 \item Item3
                 \item Item4
             \end{itemize}
         \end{center}
     \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I add a minimal working example to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `\only<2>{ ... }` instead. This should do the trick.

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress, aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcommand{\itemcolor}[1]{% Update list item colour
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\color{#1}\hfil ##1}}

\begin{document}
     \begin{frame}
         \begin{center}
             \only<2>{\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=light-gray}}
             \begin{itemize}
                 \color<2->{light-gray} 
                 \item Item1
                 \item Item2
                 \item Item3
                 \item Item4
             \end{itemize}
         \end{center}
     \end{frame}
\end{document}
```